# Purpose of MySQL support for "where col = 1 = 0"?

Tags: mysql

I recently discovered a statement in my code where I built up a MySQL statement that looks like the following:

```
select * from atable where col = 1 = 0
```

I was surprised that this actually is valid syntax - treated like "col = 0". I would like to understand why this is valid syntax and why the statement like this is not rejected. It certainly appears to be confusing, yet I just stumbled over it in logging execution, so I would never have known it was being generated otherwise. Is there a specific purpose in this format that I am missing?

Comment: Looks to me like it would take it as `(col = 1) = 0`, so it would evaluate `col = 1` as a true or false (1 or 0 respectively) then put that into the equation ending with `= 0`

Comment: I don't see why should it be invalid syntax; another issue is that this will always return nothing since col=1=0 will always be false.

Comment: icarus, it returns values as if col = 0 were true. So it does return rows where col = 0

Comment: After further testing offline it would appear that this is the behavior. col = 1 = 0 is col = (1=0) => col = false => col = 0.

col = 1 = 1 => col = (1 = 1) => col = true => col = 1

In essence with these particular values you get the same results no matter where you consider the parentheses are inferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is same as `col != 1`. It checks that `col = 1` is false.

Comment: +1 My answer assumed it would be `col =  (1 = 0)` but `(col = 1) = 0`  makes more sense.